# Eclipse Projects And Git

Tags: eclipse, git

I used computer A via the Terminal to create a) create a git repository, b) add an `index.html` file to the repo, c) add a remote origin, d) push to the remote origin. All OK.

Then, i used computer B to clone that repository via Terminal. Then, I opened `Eclipse` (equipped with `Egit`), and created a new project in the folder that was created by the cloning process. Then I used `Eclipse` to push any changes to the remote origin.

Returning to computer A, I used Eclipse to create a project in the original repo folder, and then I attempted to pull from the remote origin, in order to get the changes that were pushed when using computer B.

`Eclipse` will not do it. It complains the I have items such as `.settings`, `.project` and similar and since they are not under version control it won't overwrite them by fetching files from the server. I had to manually delete those files (via Terminal) and then Eclipse worked as expected.

Please provide information on how to avoid this.

- Should I create the local repo from within Eclipse and then push it to the remote origin, so that items such as (.settings) are under version control and (if so) how would that cause trouble to people cloning the repo and use different versions of Eclipse?
- Should I `gitignore` those items?
- Should I ask Eclipse to save its own affiliated files to another folder (not that i am aware how to do that, i only know that `NetBeans` does it)?

Comment: I like to include the .project files in source control. From the git repo view in eclipse, you should be able to clone, then IMPORT the project, and not have to create it a second time. Generally, I do exclude other things like settings files that might be system specific.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't gitignored eclipse files.

Probably, when you commit/push via egit, you also commit and push those files you already had unversioned in your machine A, so git complains, because you are asking to override existing unversioned files.

I **strongly** recommend you to gitignore those eclipse files. You can see examples of .gitignore files in the [github gitignore repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It complains because if you pull the changes from your remote it will overwrite your local files. That is the problem. The other answerer has right. You should better add all the eclipse project files and and target .settings and classpath to gitignore. You can use a global gitignore for your computers as well, before creating projects. You could use maven for example, then you can import your projects only from the pom.xml-s given in the git repository.
I use them the same. Egit and other guis are a bit too complex to work with. Git repositories can get easy in an inconsistent state where you should use the oldfashioned terminal to solve things. Like, rebasing, merging on conflicts. Gits learning curve is solid.
Now you can solve your problem if on the first computer save a backup of your original and clones your project later, after fixed it on the second. On the second git remove all this files, but use the --cached option to avoid deleting them. Before you do it so, check the help of git remove! after you have done this, put them into the .gitignore as filenames with wildcards. You can also use a global gitignore file in your user folder. Creating a .gitconfig file where you can specifiy the global ignore with the following :

```
[core]
  excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

Than just create the .gitignore_global like this :

```
/nbproject
/bin
/build.xml
.idea
chess.iml
target/
bin
```

( This file is for idea and netbeans. you can add eclipse project files here )

You can have .gitignore files per project too. You can commit them to the repository, so on the next machine you do not have to do this again. The nicest way I think is having a dotfiles git repository, which is a git repo of your home directory and the dotfiles in it. I also use it for different windows and linux distros.
That's all. You should keep all of your configuration in a safe place. And source code management can do it. But do not commit private stuff to public a place! ;)

Oh I wanted to mention that, you can also have a .gitignore entry in your .gitignore file. That can be very useful when you do not want to touch a repository but need to add a gitignore to hide some stuff especially from the given repo.